# How use the same Compile function with different equations

Tags: function-construction, compile

Say I have 2 equations that take the same parameters and variables that I want to evaluate numerically in compiled code

```
cf1 = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}}, N[a*x + b]];
```

which for example gives

```
cf1[2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

{7., 9.3, 11.6, 13.9}
```

and

```
cf2 = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}}, N[a*x^2 - b]];
```

giving

```
cf2[2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

{-2.4, 4.5, 16., 32.1}
```

How do I make a function that I can just pass whichever equation I want and the parameters and it evaluates it numerically inside the Compile without going back to `MainEvaluation`

That is

```
cf[eq1, 2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

{7., 9.3, 11.6, 13.9}
```

and

```
cf[eq2, 2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

{-2.4, 4.5, 16., 32.1}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[compile, HoldFirst];
compile[code_] := With[{cc = code},
   Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}}, cc]
   ];

cf1 = compile[N[a*x + b]];
cf1[2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

cf2 = compile[N[a*x^2 - b]];
cf2[2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> {7., 9.3, 11.6, 13.9}
>
> {-2.4, 4.5, 16., 32.1}

## Edit

Maybe this is rather more what you are looking for? It undermines the very purpose of compilation, though.

```
SetAttributes[compile, HoldFirst];
compile[code_, aa_, bb_, xx_] :=  With[{cc = code}, Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}}, cc][aa, bb, xx]];
compile[N[a*x + b], 2.3, 4.7, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself. I want to be able to call the same function twice, but with different equations as input. Here you still have to first separately compile for each equation. In my real code I have hundreds of equations that at various stages I want to evaluate with the same or slightly different parameters.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi as Henrik mentions -- that undermines the purpose of `Compilation`. What you want to do is create a compiled form of your equation for each equation of interest to make it efficient.

Comment: This answers my question, so I accept it. But I see that I will have to reformualte my problem in order to take better advantage of `Compile`